# How to create a pandas dataframe with days and hours in a year in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, for-loop

I want to create a pandas dataframe consisting of all hours in a year. Therefore, there needs to be rows for each of the 8760 hours (365 days * 24 hours per day). This is relatively straightforward.

However, I also want to have another column in the dataframe for days that corresponds to the hour. It means, until 24 hours, it'd be day 1. From 25th to 28th hour, it should Day 2 (2 in the Days column). This should be repeated until 365 days and 8760 hours.

What kind of looping technique needs to be applied for this and I want to create pandas dataframe consisting of two columns for hours and days in a year as shown below:

[image]
.
.
.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and what were your results? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thank you. I think I got my answer. I'd need to take the quotient+1 when the hour-1 is divided by 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use np.arange to create the number of hours, and then divide them by 24 to get the days?

Something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

hours = np.arange(1, 8761)
df= pd.DataFrame(data=hours, columns = ["Hours of a Year"])
df['Days of a Year'] = ((df["Hours of a Year"]-1)//24)+1
print(df)
```

Comment: it is a good way but you need to take into consideration the hours multiple to 24, they will be considered as the next day (i.e. hour 24: (24//24)+1 = day 2, while it should be still day 1

Comment: I think I got my answer. It'd be: ((df["Hours of a Year"]-1)//24)+1.

Comment: yeah, should be right then! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to populate the Day column is to ceil the division hours/24 hours per day when you populate the hour column:

```
import math    
day = math.ceil(hour / 24)
```

Or without importing the math module, using integer division:

```
day = -(-hour//24)
```

Answer (score 1):

for example

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(range(1, 24*365 + 1), columns=['hour'])
df['day'] = (df['hour'] - 1) // 24 + 1
```